# Get Office 365 Word document URL in JS Add-In code

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-js, office-addins, word-web-addins

I need to save URL to the original Office 365 Word document. I want to use this link in order to open the document from a different place.

The `Office.context.document.url` property is a link for downloading the file (this [API Office.context.document.getFilePropertiesAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.document?view=common-js-preview#office-office-document-getfilepropertiesasync-member(2)) returns the same value), so this is not what I exactly need.

Also, If such feature exists I'm curious how it works with the desktop version of MS Word.

Edit/Clarification:

I need to have a link that I can use for opening the document in browser. For instance, I want to display this link somewhere in my web app so when user clicks on it he/she is redirected to the office 365 and the document being opened.
Right now when I work with a document the link in browser has this format
https://<mycompany>-my.sharepoint.com/:w:/r/personal/<email>/_layouts/15/doc2.aspx?sourcedoc=%7B<uuid>%7D&file=Document1.docx&action=...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Isn't `Office.context.document.url` the same value as "URL to the original Office 365 Word document"? If not, what is the difference? Can you give an example of the two URLs?

Comment: @RickKirkham This value is the link for downloading the document. And I just want to redirect my user to the office online and this document. I added some details to the original question, I hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: Is the document that you want to direct the user to the same one that the user currently has open while using your add-in? If so, why do you want the user to open it a second time in a browser? Also, you've given us one URL. Now tell us the value of `Office.context.document.url` so we can see the difference.

Comment: My Add-In interacts with my separate web application where I want to store links to the documents in office online. Let's say in my web app I have a page with a list of all documents where my add-in was used. So when user opens this page I need to display links to the original document in office online.

Comment: Speaking about the `Office.context.document.url`, it contains a link with the following format  `https://<mycompany>-my.sharepoint.com/personal/<email>/Documents/Document1.docx`. And when I open this link the browser starts downloading the source doc, instead of opening it in office online. cc @RickKirkham

Comment: I feel like my question doesn't make sense or has no answer.
So I didn't find a solution for my task.